# How to replace element of list by index

Tags: functions, variable-definitions

I'd simply like to replace the value `x` at index `[[j,i]]` in a two dimensional table with the value `-x`. There doesn't seem to be an intuitive way to do this. So far I've tried:

`Flip[table_, i_, j_] := (table[[j, i]] = -table[[j, i]]; Return[table])`

However I get the error:

`Set::setps: <my table> in the part assignment is not a symbol.`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I managed to figure out my own solution: `flip[table_,j_,i_]:=MapAt[(-1*#)&,table,{{j,i}}]`. However I think `ReplacePart` fits my situation better seeing as the "flip" only needs to be done at one location in the table rather than at many. Thanks @Nasser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ReplacePart`

```
 data = RandomReal[{}, {2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
data = ReplacePart[data, {1, 2} -> -data[[1, 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You need to reassign the result back to `data`

You can make the above into a function if needed.

```
 flip[data_, i_, j_] := ReplacePart[data, {i, j} -> -data[[i, j]]];
 data = flip[data, 1, 2]
```

In your function, you also did something wrong. You can't assign to an input. So your statement  `table[[j, i]] = -table[[j, i]]` is writing to the input argument `table`. If  you really wanted to do as you show, then:

```
flip[table_, i_, j_] := 
 Module[{myTable = table}, myTable[[i, j]] = -myTable[[i, j]]; 
  myTable]
```

Now the local variable `myTable` is used to modify, then it is returned back at the  end. No need to use `Return` since by default, the last expression is the result of the function. (do not use `;` at the end, else `Null` is returned instead)

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier to use `Part`?

```
a = {{2, 3}, {4, 5}};
a[[1, 2]] = -a[[1, 2]];
a

{{2, -3}, {4, 5}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have shown you ways to do what you want in ways which are more common to Mathematica. But I think what you really ask for (though it might not necessarily the best solution for your problem) is "pass by reference" which as such does not exist in Mathematica. But there is the possibility to use `Attributes` for functions and using e.g. `HoldFirst` will make your example work as intended:

```
SetAttributes[flip, HoldFirst]
flip[table_, i_, j_] := (table[[j, i]] = -table[[j, i]]; table)
```

note that I did change the function name to start with lower case which is good practice to avoid name conflicts with Mathematica owns symbol, including future versions. It is also hardly ever necessary to use a `Return` as the last expression of a `CompoundExpression` will be returned anyway.

The `Hold*`-attribute trick will also be the solution whenever you want to make changes to an existing symbol within a function, but as such must be used with care as it will make your functions have side effects which in general make your programs much harder to understand.